# Total focus on a Form: ignore all others

Tags: vb.net, winforms

in my VB.NET application, my main Form can show other Forms. That works fine, but I need to set "focus" on the newly opened form, and don't allow the user use the main form until the opened Form is closed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Form.ShowDialog() method shows a form as a dialog box; this should keep the focus on that form until it is closed (by the user or your code).

Comment: are the forms you're trying show with focus sized so that they just cover up the main form?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Form.ShowDialog()` method.

It will show you the form as a dialog box, so focusing is at total, and it will ignore all other forms or objects.